# Java String formation for ListView

Tags: java, android, string

I have created a Java code for my Android App.

```
String[] MovieName=new String[]{};

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) 
{
MovieName[i]=movieAtt.getAttributeValue( "name" );  //Value coming from my XML
}

ListViewObject.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(screen2.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , MovieName));
```

This code throws an Exception. 
I think i am not inserting vaues properly inside Java String Array.

All i want is to have a variable like MovieName={"1","2", "3"} to feed into the ListView of my code.

This is not much helpful too : 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Throwing which exception? Can you point it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You initialize an empty array.

Try this

```
String[] MovieName = new String[15];
```

Comment: Working Great Guys. Wish i could add all of you three as answers.

Answer (score 3):

Your initilizing an empty string array. That will give you an ArrayOutOfBoundException.

If you always have 15 entries you could initialize it to 15.

```
String[] MovieName=new String[15];
```

Otherwise you could create an ArrayList and convert it to an array after you filled it.

Answer (score 1):

If number of elements in MovieName is constant, then you should initialise it as

```
String[] MovieName=new String[15];
```

Your current initialisation is equal to

```
String[] MovieName=new String[0];
```

Comment: I have a variable, that gives me children of XML. for that variable i need to run the loop. Trying it. Thanks.